# Spark Serialization DAG Error (Zeppelin)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have some Methods created in a Zeppelin note that do not serialize as a whole. But work when run with temp write/read file steps inbetween.

```
case class Visit(key: Long, uri: String, visits: Long)
def removeURIParams(uri:String) = ...
def splitUri(visit: Visit):Seq[Visit] = { uses removeURIParams }

val fileByUser =  "urisGroupedByUser.parquet"
val fileByUserTemp =  "urisGroupedByUserTemp.parquet"

def filterViableByUsersDAG(minTF:Int) = {
    val dfViableByDay = spark.read.parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByDay)
    val df = dfVisits
        .select($"uuid".as("key"),$"uri")
        .join(dfViableByDay.select($"original".as("uri")),"uri")
        .groupBy($"key",$"uri")
        .agg(count($"uri").as("visits"))
        .as[Visit]
        .flatMap(splitUri)
        .groupBy($"key", $"uri")
        .agg(sum($"visits").as("visits"))
        .groupBy($"uri").agg(count($"key").as("count")).where($"count" > minTF).repartition(1)
    df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByUser)
    df
}
```

The exact steps don't matter or what I am trying to do. What I want to know is why I get a Serialization error when I run filterViableByUsersDAG at once.

e.g. split

```
def filterViableByUsers(minTF:Int) = {
    val dfViableByDay = spark.read.parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByDay)
    dfVisits
        .select($"uuid".as("key"),$"uri")
        .join(dfViableByDay.select($"original".as("uri")),"uri")
        .groupBy($"key",$"uri")
        .agg(count($"uri").as("visits"))
        .write.mode("overwrite").parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByDayTemp)
    spark.read.parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByDayTemp)
        .as[Visit]
        .flatMap(splitUri)
        .write.mode("overwrite").parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByUserSplit)
    val df = spark.read.parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByUserSplit)
        .groupBy($"key", $"uri")
        .agg(sum($"visits").as("visits"))
        .groupBy($"uri").agg(count($"key").as("count")).where($"count" > minTF).repartition(1)
    df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(mltrainingBasePath + fileByUser)
    df
}
```

The exact same code works without any serialization issues. But I write a temp parquet File in between each step. Which cannot be the solution.

Errors are:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: uri)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Column;, size 3)
    - field (class: $line58092229620.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: columns, type: class [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Column;)
...
```

---

```
+- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit), obj#223: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, visits#211L])
      +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[partial_count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, count#261L])
         +- *Project [uri#2, key#197L]
            +- *SortMergeJoin [uri#2], [uri#201], Inner
               :- *Sort [uri#2 ASC], false, 0
               :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#2, 200)
               :     +- Union
               :        :- *Project [uuid#4L AS key#197L, uri#2]
               :        :  +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#2)
               :        :     +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#2,uuid#4L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
               :        +- *Project [uuid#43L AS key#197L, uri#41]
               :           +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#41)
               :              +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#41,uuid#43L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
               +- *Sort [uri#201 ASC], false, 0
                  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#201, 200)
                     +- *Project [original#191 AS uri#201]
                        +- *Filter isnotnull(original#191)
                           +- *BatchedScan parquet [original#191] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/mltraining/urisGroupedByDay.parquet, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(original)], ReadSchema: struct<original:string>
)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter, MapPartitions <function1>, obj#224: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
+- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit), obj#223: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, visits#211L])
      +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[partial_count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, count#261L])
         +- *Project [uri#2, key#197L]
            +- *SortMergeJoin [uri#2], [uri#201], Inner
               :- *Sort [uri#2 ASC], false, 0
               :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#2, 200)
               :     +- Union
               :        :- *Project [uuid#4L AS key#197L, uri#2]
               :        :  +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#2)
               :        :     +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#2,uuid#4L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
               :        +- *Project [uuid#43L AS key#197L, uri#41]
               :           +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#41)
               :              +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#41,uuid#43L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
               +- *Sort [uri#201 ASC], false, 0
                  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#201, 200)
                     +- *Project [original#191 AS uri#201]
                        +- *Filter isnotnull(original#191)
                           +- *BatchedScan parquet [original#191] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/mltraining/urisGroupedByDay.parquet, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(original)], ReadSchema: struct<original:string>
)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SerializeFromObjectExec, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SerializeFromObjectExec, SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).key AS key#225L, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).uri, true) AS uri#226, assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).visits AS visits#227L]
+- MapPartitions <function1>, obj#224: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
   +- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit), obj#223: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
      +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, visits#211L])
         +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[partial_count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, count#261L])
            +- *Project [uri#2, key#197L]
               +- *SortMergeJoin [uri#2], [uri#201], Inner
                  :- *Sort [uri#2 ASC], false, 0
                  :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#2, 200)
                  :     +- Union
                  :        :- *Project [uuid#4L AS key#197L, uri#2]
                  :        :  +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#2)
                  :        :     +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#2,uuid#4L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
                  :        +- *Project [uuid#43L AS key#197L, uri#41]
                  :           +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#41)
                  :              +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#41,uuid#43L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
                  +- *Sort [uri#201 ASC], false, 0
                     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#201, 200)
                        +- *Project [original#191 AS uri#201]
                           +- *Filter isnotnull(original#191)
                              +- *BatchedScan parquet [original#191] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/mltraining/urisGroupedByDay.parquet, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(original)], ReadSchema: struct<original:string>
)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec, Project [key#225L, uri#226]
+- SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).key AS key#225L, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).uri, true) AS uri#226, assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).visits AS visits#227L]
   +- MapPartitions <function1>, obj#224: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
      +- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit), obj#223: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
         +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, visits#211L])
            +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[partial_count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, count#261L])
               +- *Project [uri#2, key#197L]
                  +- *SortMergeJoin [uri#2], [uri#201], Inner
                     :- *Sort [uri#2 ASC], false, 0
                     :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#2, 200)
                     :     +- Union
                     :        :- *Project [uuid#4L AS key#197L, uri#2]
                     :        :  +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#2)
                     :        :     +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#2,uuid#4L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
                     :        +- *Project [uuid#43L AS key#197L, uri#41]
                     :           +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#41)
                     :              +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#41,uuid#43L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
                     +- *Sort [uri#201 ASC], false, 0
                        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#201, 200)
                           +- *Project [original#191 AS uri#201]
                              +- *Filter isnotnull(original#191)
                                 +- *BatchedScan parquet [original#191] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/mltraining/urisGroupedByDay.parquet, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(original)], ReadSchema: struct<original:string>
)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec, HashAggregate(keys=[key#225L, uri#226], functions=[], output=[key#225L, uri#226])
+- Project [key#225L, uri#226]
   +- SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).key AS key#225L, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).uri, true) AS uri#226, assertnotnull(input[0, $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit, true], top level non-flat input object).visits AS visits#227L]
      +- MapPartitions <function1>, obj#224: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
         +- DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit), obj#223: $line58092229685.$read$$iw$$iw$Visit
            +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, visits#211L])
               +- *HashAggregate(keys=[key#197L, uri#2], functions=[partial_count(uri#2)], output=[key#197L, uri#2, count#261L])
                  +- *Project [uri#2, key#197L]
                     +- *SortMergeJoin [uri#2], [uri#201], Inner
                        :- *Sort [uri#2 ASC], false, 0
                        :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#2, 200)
                        :     +- Union
                        :        :- *Project [uuid#4L AS key#197L, uri#2]
                        :        :  +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#2)
                        :        :     +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#2,uuid#4L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
                        :        +- *Project [uuid#43L AS key#197L, uri#41]
                        :           +- *Filter isnotnull(uri#41)
                        :              +- *BatchedScan parquet [uri#41,uuid#43L] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161230.parquet, file:/local_data/sensor/sensor_event.20161..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(uri)], ReadSchema: struct<uri:string,uuid:bigint>
                        +- *Sort [uri#201 ASC], false, 0
                           +- Exchange hashpartitioning(uri#201, 200)
                              +- *Project [original#191 AS uri#201]
                                 +- *Filter isnotnull(original#191)
                                    +- *BatchedScan parquet [original#191] Format: ParquetFormat, InputPaths: file:/local_data/mltraining/urisGroupedByDay.parquet, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(original)], ReadSchema: struct<original:string>
)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 8)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, <function2>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    ... 138 more
```

Comment: Try to break down your code to isolate when it's actually breaking. Plus I suspect it has something to do with splitUri and removeURIParams. Honestly it's a bit broad to debug.

Comment: I also think there's something inside `splitUri` and `removeURIParams` that causes the error. Just think about a reproducible example like `Seq(Visit(0, "uri", 5)).toDS.flatMap(splitUri).show`. That should lead to the same error.